# Why are not all five of the circles being drawn to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw 5 random circles to a canvas that I hope to at some point make in to a centipede game. I have my logic set up so that a for loop loops through 5 circles. Then there is a do loop that makes certain that the circles X and Y points are in the canvas because at some point they will all have to be in an array so that I can determine if they have been hit by the player.

If the coordinates are no good then I simple loop again in the do-loop to get another set of X and Y coordinates. If a pair of cords is OK then I enter the if-statement and set isDrawable equal to TRUE.

Question: What simple logic do I need to change to make this always draw 5 visible circles on the canvas?

Code:

```
function buildCircle() {
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
      do { 
        isDrawable = false;
        radX = Math.random()*theCanvas.width;
        radY = Math.random()*theCanvas.height;
        radR = Math.random()*10+3;
console.log(i);
console.log(radX);   
console.log(radY);    
            if ((radX>5 && radX<435) && (radY>0 && radY<520)) {
                isDrawable = true;
                canvasContext.fillStyle='#123321;'  //getRandomColor();
                drawCircle(radX,radY,radR,canvasContext);
            }   
console.log(isDrawable);    
        } 
        while (isDrawable = false);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of the do while loop is wrong. You should set "isDrawable == false" instead of "isDrawable = false".

Comment: Thank you that made it work. if you were going to put them into an array how would you go about doing that?

Comment: If you mean put the circles into an array, you should create an array of objects with the definitions of each circle (for example, arr = [ {rX: 0, rY: 0, rR: 0},{rX: 0, rY: 0, rR: 0}, {rX: 0, rY: 0, rR: 0}, {rX: 0, rY: 0, rR: 0} ], and modify each value in the inner if: arr[i].rX =...; arr[i].rY =...; ... Then paint the array when you want , at that moment or after the for...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I see the problem with the original code, but if your problem is the loop and do/whilte, this should work and is probably more easily read:

```
var circlesLeft = 5;
while (circlesLeft) {
  //stuff
  if (draw_circle) {
    //draw circle
    --circlesLeft;
  }
}
```

The only other potential problem I see with your code is that it doesn't handle if two circles chose the same (or very close to the same) coordinates, they would overlap and while you drew two, only one (the largest) would be visible.

Comment: if they over lap for the time being that is alright. Can you put up a qorking fiddle of your idea.

Comment: How would I store them in an array so that later I can put an image of a muchroom and then detect if it has been hit.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you want to make sure each circle is completely inside the canvas. A circle in `(x, y)` with radius `r` is inside the canvas if, and only if:

- `x-r>=0`
- `x+r<=width`
- `y-r>=0`
- `y+r<=height`

That is:

- `r <= x <= width-r`
- `r <= y <= height-r`

So, a simpler logic would be to apply the limits right to your random generator. First you pick a random radius `r=3+Math.random()*10`, then pick:

- `x` in `[r, width-r]`
- `y` in `[r, height-r]`

That gives you: `x = r+(width-2*r)*Math.random()` and `y = r+(height-2*r)*Math.random()`

If you want to avoid a circle on top of another, then you'll need a similar logic of trial and error: for every new circle, pick random `(x, y)` and `r` as above, then check if it doesn't collide with any previous circle. If it does, try again.

The logic for checking collision is simply checking if the distance is greater than the radius combined:

```
function checkCollision(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2) {
    return (x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2) > (r1+r2)*(r1+r2) // true if don't collide
}
```